# Does a $W^*$ envelope exist?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

I know that an operator algebra $A$ has a "minimal" $C^*$-algebra $C$ containing $A$, which is known as the $C^*$ envelope of $A$. The existence of such a minimal $C^*$-algebra generated by $A$ (a minimal $C^*$ cover for $A$) is well known.

On the other hand, any dual operator algebra $A$ generates $W^*$-algebras. For example, there is a maximal $W^*$ cover of $A$, which I've seen denoted by $W^{*}_{max}(A)$. My question is: is it known that a minimal $W^*$ cover exist? That is, does a dual operator algebra has a $W^*$ envelope?

Comment: Are you conidering $A$ here a sub-algebra of operators of a given Hilbert space, or do you have in mind an "abstract" Banach algebra and you wish to define a ctegorical envelope  considering all possible representations?

Comment: I'm talking about an abstract dual operator algebra $A$ (that is, there is a Hilbert space H and a w$^{*}$-continuous completely isometric isomorphism $\pi:A\to B(H)$  ).  I want to know if anybody has proven that there is a minimal $W^{*}$-algebra generated by $A$ (yes, considering all representations, just like in the case of the $C^{*}$-envelope of an operator algebra).

Comment: epsilon, I erased an answer I previously posted because I realized it is was of your point.

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is: It's not known. It's an open problem.

Comment: Epsilon, I think it is hasty to say "the answer is not known" - not every operator algebraist reads MathOverflow, and those who do might not have seen your question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two ways, algebraically by taking its bicommutant (if is is realised as an algebra of operators on a Hilbert space), or topologically by taking its completion in the bounded weak topology, i.e., the finest locally convex topology which agrees with the weak topology on the unit ball.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are familiar with the $C^{*}$ envelope of an operator algebra. In the case of a dual operator algebra ,we have to consider the $W^{*}$ algebras generated by ALL weak$^{*}$ continuous completely isometric homomorphisms $j:A\to B$ such that $B$ is generated as a $W^{*}$-algebra by $j(A)$. From all these $W^{*}$-algebras, is there a minimal one?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious attempt to construct a W$^*$-envelope like the C$^*$-envelope fails because if $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is an injective von Neumann algebra there may not be a normal contraction from $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ onto $\mathcal{M}$, e.g. if $\mathcal{M}$ is not purely atomic.

I think there are pretty strong obstructions to the usefulness of such an object even in the commutative case, although I can't immediately see how to use them to rule out a W$^*$-envelope altogether.

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a commutative operator algebra whose C$^*$-envelope is $\mathrm{C}([0, 1])$, then its injective envelope is the Dixmier algebra of bounded Borel functions on $[0, 1]$ modulo the ideal of functions with meagre support. See [this paper of Blecher and Magajna](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407220) for a proof. The Dixmier algebra is an AW$^*$-algebra that is not a W$^*$-algebra, and it has no normal linear functionals.

Since any commutative W$^*$-algebra is injective, any W$^*$-envelope of a commutative operator algebra whose C$^*$-envelope is $\mathrm{C}([0, 1])$ has to contain the Dixmier algebra and every embedding of a dual operator algebra in its W$^*$-envelope would have to factor through the Dixmier algebra.

The [pure state space of the Dixmier algebra is separable](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-12/4/431.extract), so it has many faithful representations on separable Hilbert spaces, but it certainly seems that there is no canonical representation.